# Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item

Tags: workflow, publishing, content-approval, workflow-template

How can i uncheck the option/setting  "***Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item***"  in a publishing approval workflow of a pages library of publishing site.

I found other settings like  Association.AutoStartChange=true; and                                                                                                        Association.AutoStartCreate=true; but i am unable to uncheck this option through programatically.

Any idea ?

Thanks
Purna

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the association ID of the workflow and set following property to set it programmatically.

SPList.DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId

Answer (score 1):

check this out:

WorkflowContext.AllowDefaultContentApproval

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.workflowcontext.allowdefaultcontentapproval.aspx

SPWorkflowTemplate.AllowDefaultContentApproval

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowtemplate.allowdefaultcontentapproval.aspx

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the workflow instances
>   based on this template can start automatically when the user attempts
>   to approve publishing a major version of an item.
>
> true if the workflow instances based on this template can start
>   automatically when the user attempts to approve publishing a major
>   version of an item; otherwise, false.

```
SPWorkflowTemplate template = web.WorkflowTemplates.GetTemplateByBaseID(new Guid("AB81DB45-4CDD-4650-80CD-6EFC53D2D9EC")); 
               template.AllowDefaultContentApproval = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this workflow is a custom created workflow?

Try to see [this](http://jamestsai.net/Blog/post/Why-Start-this-workflow-to-approve-publishing-a-major-version-of-an-item-option-is-disabled-for-my-custom-workflow-in-SharePoint.aspx) post if it helps

[This](http://thorprojects.com/blog/archive/2011/10/01/writing-your-own-sharepoint-publishing-approval-workflow.aspx) is how to edit using SPD

Andrew